# Trouble with errorband and nested properties

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I'm having some trouble with the `errorband` mark type. It seems to only work with fields at the top level of the data. In my case, the data has pre-aggregated statistics in nested properties. I've modified the `errorband` example from the documentation to show the problem:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"stddev" : {"upper": 34.5007, "lower": 30.6912}, "center": 32.5735, "Year": 189302400000, "mfg": "Toyota"},
      {"stddev" : {"upper": 36.8214, "lower": 31.8554}, "center": 34.375, "Year": 220924800000, "mfg": "Toyota"},
      {"stddev" : {"upper": 37.4472, "lower": 32.9749}, "center": 35.0611, "Year": 252460800000, "mfg": "Toyota"},
      {"stddev" : {"upper": 38.7074, "lower": 33.6203}, "center": 36.0931, "Year": 283996800000, "mfg": "Toyota"},
      {"stddev" : {"upper": 23.5007, "lower": 19.6912}, "center": 21.5735, "Year": 189302400000, "mfg": "Ford"},
      {"stddev" : {"upper": 25.8214, "lower": 20.8554}, "center": 23.375, "Year": 220924800000, "mfg": "Ford"},
      {"stddev" : {"upper": 26.4472, "lower": 21.9749}, "center": 24.0611, "Year": 252460800000, "mfg": "Ford"},
      {"stddev" : {"upper": 27.7074, "lower": 22.6203}, "center": 25.0931, "Year": 283996800000, "mfg": "Ford"}
    ]
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "errorband"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "stddev.upper",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "scale": {"zero": false},
          "title": "Mean of Miles per Gallon (95% CIs)"
        },
        "y2": {"field": "stddev.lower"},
        "x": {"field": "Year", "timeUnit": "year"},
        "color": {"field": "mfg", "type": "nominal"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "color": {"field": "mfg", "type": "nominal"},
        "y": {"field": "center", "type": "quantitative"},
        "x": {"field": "Year", "timeUnit": "year"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The logs in the vega-editor show it looking for fields called `lower_stddev.upper` and `upper_stddev.upper`:

```
    [Warning] Infinite extent for field "lower_stddev.upper": [Infinity, -Infinity]
    [Warning] Infinite extent for field "upper_stddev.upper": [Infinity, -Infinity]
```

I've tried changing the the `extent` in the mark configuration, but to no avail.

I see that `vega` has a `project` transformation that looks like it would help to flatten these nested properties, but it seems this transformation isn't available in `vega-lite`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found that unpacking the `errorband` macro as described in the documentation worked fine. Also, the `calculate` transformation worked:

```json
"transform": [
  {"calculate": "datum.stddev.upper", "as": "upper"}, 
  {"calculate": "datum.stddev.lower", "as": "lower"}
]
```